# NSNumberFormatter Handling of Very High Precision Decimals Reduced from Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, decimal, nsnumberformatter

Xcode 12 and below used to be able to handle decimals with many more digits than Xcode 13. The below code on Xcode 12 & 13 produces very different result:

```swift
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 16
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false

formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(string: "1234567890123456.1234567890123456"))
// Xcode 12: "1234567890123456.1234567890123456"
// Xcode 13: "1234567890123460.0"
```

Interestingly, switching to `usesSignificantDigits` alleviated the issue, but I'm looking for the behaviour of `maximumFractionDigits` in my feature instead.

Did Apple reimplemented something that changes this behaviour? What can we do to get back the higher precision of the Xcode 12 formatter?

Comment: Please use Apple’s bug reporting system and enter a ticket. Also it’s not Xcode doing this - that formatter is built into iOS. It’s likely this was intentional and may be buried in some release note.

Comment: I should also add that fully configuring objects like formatters is the best approach. You can never assume Apple’s defaults won’t change over time.